# Mysql database with spring roo

Tags: mysql, spring-roo

I have created a spring roo project with mqsql database.When i run the project it is working perfectly.But when i restart the server all the data that i stored previously in the table is deleted.This is happening whenever i restart the server.Can anybody tell me a solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the file  / src / main / resources / META-INF / persistence.xml

There is an entry called something like **hibernate.hbm2.dll.auto**.

Set it to validate (update or whatever, as indicate the commentary)

You can also delete it if you don't need Hibernate to manage the database.

Comment: Thanks Mr jbbarquero i set <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> in the persistence.xml file.Now the problem solved.